# Calculating big numbers with mod and pow

Tags: c++, pow, cmath, modulo

i was trying to solve the big mod problem using the following code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

typedef long int li;

li m;
li mod(li b,li p)
{
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    if(p%2==0)
    {
        return ((mod(b,p/2)%m)*mod(b,p/2)%m)%m;
        //return (li)pow(mod(b,p/2)%m,2)%m;
    }
    return (b%m*mod(b,p-1)%m)%m;
}

main()
{
    li b,p;
    while(cin>>b>>p>>m)
    {
        cout<<mod(b,p)<<endl;
    }
}
```

but it gives different output for ((mod(b,p/2)%m)*mod(b,p/2)%m)%m and pow(mod(b,p/2)%m,2)%m.i want to know are they not the same and if they are why are the giving different outputs.

sample input:
3
18132
17

17
1765
3

2374859
3029382
36123

output without pow function:
13
2
13195

output with pow function:
1
2
31329

test code with pow function

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef long int li;

li m;
li mod(li b,li p)
{
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    if(p%2==0)
    {
        //return ((mod(b,p/2)%m)*mod(b,p/2)%m)%m;
        return (li)pow(mod(b,p/2)%m,2)%m;
    }
    return (b%m*mod(b,p-1)%m)%m;
}

main()
{
    li b,p;
    while(cin>>b>>p>>m)
    {
        cout<<mod(b,p)<<endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide the input and output!

Comment: Please provide working code.

Comment: please provide ice cream!

Comment: First of all, a few pieces of advice not directly relevant to your problem. 1. You should surely pass `m` into your function as an actual parameter, not via a global variable. (*Possible* exception: if this is going to be used for large calculations all using the same modulus.) 2. You shouldn't call it `mod` because that already has a meaning and it's a different meaning. Maybe `pmod` or `mpow` or `expmod` or something that indicates you're doing both exponentiation and remaindering. 3. You have some superfluous `%m`%s; e.g., the result of `mod` is always already "in range".

Comment: Oh, also 4. You shouldn't be calling `mod(b,p/2)` twice, but calling it once and multiplying the result by itself. This will make a very large difference to efficiency.

Comment: You've given some sample input but no sample output. Can you show us a case it definitely gets wrong? (Or, if you prefer, two cases where you're sure one of them must be wrong even if you can't tell which?)

Comment: thank you  Gareth McCaughan, I will keep those in mind next time

Comment: The reason you give for thinking your `mod` function is doing the wrong thing seems peculiar, for two reasons. First, taken at face value it sounds like you're calling `pow`, which is meant for use with floating-point numbers rather than integers. Second, the things you're comparing all involve `mod(b,p/2)` and no other calls to `mod`, and if there's a discrepancy between them it can't be `mod`'s fault.

Comment: Not quite sure but are you trying to build a powmod(a,x,m) function based on [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring)?

Comment: Oh, another minor thing: I think you (i.e., Reshad) may be a little confused about the precedence of the `*` and `%` operators. E.g., `(b%m*mod(...)%m)%m` is actually the same as `(((b%m)*mod(...))%m)%m` which probably isn't what you had in mind since it reduces the same thing mod m twice in a row. This doesn't end up actually breaking any of your code, as it happens.

Comment: As you will see, I think your problem is in your test code rather than your modular-exponentiation code. Could you post that too? In particular, whatever you used to get the "with pow function" outputs?

Comment: #include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

typedef long int li;

li m;
li mod(li b,li p)
{
    if(p==0)
        return 1;
    if(p%2==0)
    {
        //return ((mod(b,p/2)%m)*mod(b,p/2)%m)%m;
        return (li)pow(mod(b,p/2)%m,2)%m;
    }
    return (b%m*mod(b,p-1)%m)%m;
}

main()
{
    li b,p;
    while(cin>>b>>p>>m)
    {
        cout<<mod(b,p)<<endl;
    }
}

Comment: Please use the [edit "button"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/36596017/edit) to add the (neatly formatted) code to your question text.

Comment: Thanks for posting the two versions of the code. I've updated my answer to explain in more detail what's going wrong with the `pow` version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answers you report "without pow function" are correct answers, and your code looks OK to me. So I think **your problem is in the test you're applying**, not in your modular exponentiation function.

The `pow` function operates on (double-precision) floating-point numbers, and is not guaranteed to give exact results even when both its inputs are small integers. What is happening to you is that at some point `pow` is returning a value that is just a tiny bit smaller than an integer, and then you cast it to `long int` and get a value 1 less than you "should", and after that everything is wrong.

For instance, if you compute 3^6 mod 17 with your code, then at one point it gets 3^3 mod 17 = 10 (OK so far), then computes pow(10,2) ... and, at least on my machine with my compiler, this comes out to just a little bit less than 100. So the cast to `li` yields 99 instead of 100, and then we're dead.

I have tried to verify this in more detail by instrumenting your code to output intermediate values, but amusingly this typically fails because of subtleties in floating-point arithmetic. (Saving an intermediate value in a variable can cause it to be subject to an extra floating-point rounding which turns the just-less-than-an-integer value into an exact integer value.)

Comment: yes that is I tried type conversion but it still gives the wrong results. I just want to understand why is it wrong.

Comment: In order to say what is wrong with your test code, we will need to see your test code.

Comment: may be using pow function for this task was a bad idea. thanks for help